# Str.split and time.sleep python when executed output is coming as the word+ none

Tags: python

Whenever i try to split the str in my code with `str.split` and `time.sleep` the output comes as the word + none

I want this string to split and print the word every 0.3sec . I am really confused bcoz i am beginner.

```
import time

lyrics_str=('''class is starting today''')
for word in lyrics_str.split():
    print('''        
          '''  ,word    ,time.sleep(0.3) )
```

The out come is this

```
class None
is None
starting None
today None
```

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the output of the sleep function which (unsurprisingly perhaps) doesn't return anything!

What your really want to do is print *and then* sleep:

```py
import time

lyrics_str = "class is starting today"
for word in lyrics_str.split():
    print(word)
    time.sleep(0.3)
```